# Can't add to an ArrayList on Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, arrays

[image]

I'm not sure what's causing such warning. 
Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add objects. This is just a warning that your list is not generic.

To make it generic, it should be:

```
List<String> quotes = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 1):

First to make your `list` generic and after that initialize and after that use it.
Ex:-

```
public List<String> qoutes;
qoutes = new ArrayList<>();
```

And after that..

```
qoutes.add("Something...");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to (and should) develop against generic data type...

Your compiler is asking "what is this arrayList containing?", even more, you should use the interfaces for that:

```
List<E> quotes = new ArrayList<E>(); where E is just a place holder for your Class
```

Answer (score 0):

**quotes list** contains String objects, So you need to define ArrayList like below,

```
 ArrayList<String> quotes = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now warning will go away, and you can add string objects in this list.

Hope it will help !

Answer (score 0):

You have to simply provide generics for the same.Give it String as you are passing String to your list.

```
ArrayList<String> quotes = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score -1):

change your **ArrayList to ArrayList.**

This warning comes because **you haven't used generics.**

Chnage your code to :

```
public ArrayList<String> quotes;
```

Let me know if this works for you! :)